# Como corrigir o que está vermelho?

Tags: android-studio

Sou iniciante e não estou conseguindo consertar o que está em vermelho na imagem quando mudei para o código mudou de cor mas no Android Studio assim https://i.stack.imgur.com/SCAR6.jpg

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {                                 

    private ViewManager l;                                                   

    @Override                                                                
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {                     
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);                                  
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);                              


        String s = "";                                                       
        for (int i = 1; i <= 45; i +=6) {                                    
            TextView t = new TextView(this);                                 
            t.setText(s);                                                    
            l.addView(t);                                                    
        }                                                                    
        int x = 2;                                                           
        do {                                                                 
            Button b = new Button(this);                                     
            b.setText(x);                                                    
            l.addView(b);                                                    
            if (x == 7 && x == 13 && x == 19)                                
                continue;                                                    
        } while (x <= 24);                                                   


    }                                                                        
}
```

Comment: Sandra, por favor, troque a sua imagem pelo código escrito, assim, quem quiser te ajudar, poderá copiar o seu código para analisa-lo com mais facilidade.

Answer (score 1):

Ele ficou em vermelho porque não tem como a variável `x` ter o 3 valores ao mesmo tempo, você está usando o operador `&&`:

```
if (x == 7 && x == 13 && x == 19)
```

Seria como dizer x tem que ser igual a 7, 13 e 19 ao mesmo tempo, é como se o *IDE* estivesse lhe dando uma dica que o nunca será possível entrar naquele `if`.

Acredito que você desejar seja o "OU", variável `x` tem quer 7 ou 13 ou 19, se for isto mesmo faça assim:

```
if (x == 7 || x == 13 || x == 19)
```

Aprenda a diferença dos *operadores* em https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html

| Tipo | Operadores |
| --- | --- |
| Sufixais | `expr++` `expr--` |
| Prefixais | `++expr` `--expr` `+expr` `-expr` `~` `!` |
| Multiplicativos | `*` `/` `%` |
| Aditivos | `+` `-` |
| Shift Binário | `<<` `>>` `>>>` |
| Comparativos | `<` `>` `<=` `>=` `instanceof` |
| igualdade | `==` `!=` |
| Bit-aBit E | `&` |
| Bit-aBit XOU OR | `^` |
| Bit-aBit OU OR | `|` |
| Lógico E | `&&` |
| Lógico OU | `||` |
| Ternário | `?` `:` |
| Atribuição | `=` `+=` `-=` `*=` `/=` `%=` `&=` `^=` `|=` `<<=` `>>=` `>>>=` |